# Passing a value to a HTML input text box and displaying it

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first question on StackOverflow. Apologies if I may seem to deviate from the rules.

I have two text boxes and a submit button. The idea is, the user types a number, such as 7, in the first input box. The second input box is to display "Seven" when the submit button is clicked on. The first text box is of id "userInput" while the second one is of id "userOutput".

As a preliminary test, I have the following code segment in javascript but doesn't seem to work at all;

```
function toTest()
{
    if (document.getElementById("inputUser").value==7) {
        document.getElementById("outputUser").value=="Seven";
    } else {
        window.alert("Functionality not added");
    }
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Such questions are considered too broad. Read [mcve] to understand what can you ask here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: In a broad sense, you'll want to create an array ["zero","one","two","three"...], then use the user's input as the index to pull a value out of that array and set the second input's value (secondInput.value = ...) to the value you've pulled. Show what you've got, we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
FirstBox <input id="first" type="text" name="fname"><br>
SecondBox <input id="second" type="text" name="lname"><br>
<button onclick="givevalue()" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

javascript

```
givevalue = function(){
   console.log("hello")
   var value = document.getElementById('first').value;
   document.getElementById('second').value = value;

}
```

JS fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/64w6yjxv/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

Javascript

```
var th = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion'];
// uncomment this line for English Number System
// var th = ['','thousand','million', 'milliard','billion'];

var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',             'eight', 'nine'];
var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen',     'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
var tw = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

function toWords(s) {
    s = s.toString();
    s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
    if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number';
    var x = s.indexOf('.');
    if (x == -1) x = s.length;
    if (x > 15) return 'too big';
    var n = s.split('');
    var str = '';
    var sk = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
            if (n[i] == '1') {
                str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
                i++;
                sk = 1;
            } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
                sk = 1;
            }
        } else if (n[i] != 0) {
            str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
            sk = 1;
        }
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
            if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
            sk = 0;
        }
    }
    if (x != s.length) {
        var y = s.length;
        str += 'point ';
        for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
    }
    return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
}

$("#convert").click(function(){
  $("#word").val(toWords($("#number").val())); 
});
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="number"></br>
<input type="text" id="word">
<input type="button" id="convert" value="convert">
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/nzRje/257/

Answer (score 0):

Use only 1 `=` instead of 2 `==`.
So change:

```
document.getElementById("outputUser").value=="Seven";
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById("outputUser").value="Seven";
```

2 means equal to and 1 means set to.
See the 'assignment operators' section at [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp) for reference.
Hope this works!